# All in one QR code + Barcode + OCR same like iPhone camera

Tags: iphone, flutter, ocr, qr-code, barcode

Developing Flutter app where I am looking for an example or libs where single camera has all functionalities to scan QR code, Barcode and OCR same like builtin iPhone device's camera.

I have been doing R&D for 5 hours but not able to find such an example but defiantly got some awesome libs like below.

- https://scanbot.io/trial/demo-app/
- https://fluttergems.dev/qr-code-bar-code/

And etc. But not exactly that I want *(same like iPhone camera feature)* So I thought, I should ask question here so might be get some help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean under 'same like iPhone camera feature'?

Comment: @powerman23rus - like https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208843 you can see there QR code is scanning and bottom right OCR is enable

Comment: so you want to see a notification with recognized text/link?

Comment: Simple open camera where I can do either qr code scan or barcode scan or ocr

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure that you can find all 3 in one library but you can use the:

- [scan](https://pub.dev/packages/scan) library that allows you to parse as well as QR and Barcode
- [flutter_mobile_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobile_vision/install) for OCR

You also can combine those in the class that repeatedly try to recognize the image with different recognizers.

I try to explain in pseudocode:

```
// Abstract class to declare the interface
abstract class RecognizeProvider {
    bool canScan(Image image);
    String scan(Image image);
}

// Classes to recognize different types of codes
class QrRecognizer implements RecognizeProvider { ... }
class BarcodeRecognizer implements RecognizeProvider { ... }
class OcrRecognizer implements RecognizeProvider { ... }

// Class which will responsible for choosing the recognizer
class ScanRecogniser(List<RecognizeProvider> this.recognizers) {
    String scan(Image image) {
        final recognizer recognizers.firstWhere(recognizer) => recognizer.canScan(image));
        return recognizer.scan(image);
    }
}

void main() {
    final scanner = ScanRecogniser([QrRecognizer(), BarcodeRecognizer(), OcrRecognizer()]);
    final image = await Camera()...;
    final result = scanner.scan(image);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - That I know there are multiple libs that I can use or combine to achieve this functionality but looking for all in one. :)

Answer (score -1):

I feel you on the struggle of finding the right libraries for your Flutter app. Have you checked out [Smart Engines](https://smartengines.com/)? They offer OCR technology that could come in handy for your project. As for the all-in-one camera functionality you're looking for, I'm not sure if there's a specific library that replicates the iPhone camera feature, but those demo apps you linked seem promising. Keep tinkering and I'm sure you'll find a solution that works for you. Good luck, mate!